# How to export BLOB data from MySQL to be embeded into spreadsheets like Kingsoft or Excel

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Is there any way to automatically embed blob attachment into excel?

Header1  | Header2  | Header3 | Attachment

Record11 | Record12 | Record13| Blob data 1

My current method is output stream of text to a file in csv.

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=Report.csv");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < grdReport.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        sb.Append(grdReport.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
    }
    sb.Append("\r\n");


    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdReport.Rows)
    {
        Label label1 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCompany");
        Label label2 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblDocNum");
        Label label3 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblDocType");

        string str = label1.Text + "," + label2.Text + "," + label3.Textt;
        sb.Append(str);
        sb.Append("\r\n");

    }

    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Where's your blob? Are you asking how to embed a blob into a CSV file?

Comment: Hi John thanks for the welcome. Is that possible since csv and my method is just output plain text? Or we need to use excel COM interop capability?

Comment: My point was to get you to realize that .csv is just a text file, so cannot contain a blob.

Comment: Also, it is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Finally, even if you had Excel running on your desktop, what would you do with a blob?

Comment: It's a user requirement, when we generate an excel reports - the generated report will also contain embedded attachments like scanned image, pdf and etc.